# How to take count of specific fields in same table using sub queries and assign specific names for those sub quesries to get data

Tags: mysql

I am saving some MCQ type questions and user's answers in a MySQL database.
This is the table for saving all user answers according to the given questions.
[image]

I want to take data according to the `question_id` and `session_code`.
There are only 4 answers to these MCQ questions.
So if I take `question_id = 8`, I want to get all the counts of answers 1 to 4. 
Like this :

[image]

I tried to do this using a code like this and it's not working...

```
SELECT DISTINCT question_id , (select COUNT(user_selected_answer)
from user_answers
where 
session_code = 8888 and user_selected_answer = 1 ) as Ans1 ,
(select COUNT(user_selected_answer) from user_answers where session_code = 8888 and user_selected_answer = 2 ) as Ans2 ,
(select COUNT(user_selected_answer) from user_answers where session_code = 8888 and user_selected_answer = 3 ) as Ans3 ,
(select COUNT(user_selected_answer) from user_answers where session_code = 8888 and user_selected_answer = 4 ) as Ans4 
FROM `user_answers` 
WHERE session_code = 8888
```

Please help me with this...
Thanks.

Comment: can u please update with a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `group by`

```
SELECT COUNT(user_selected_answer) FROM user_answers WHERE session_code = 888 GROUP BY question_id
```

Comment: no no men I want a list of all. Not this hard coded question_id. Check the 2nd image. I want a list of answers and counts.